# undefined symbol: _ZN2df12KinectFusion10save_modelESs from kinect_fusion

Tags: runtime, kinect, kinect-sdk, undefined-symbol

I do not have too much experience on kinect fusion. I am reproducing a framework from a paper, which requires kinect fusion. I can successfully compile kinect fusion. However, When I try to `import kfusion` for testing. It fails as :

`+ set -e
+ export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=True
+ PYTHONUNBUFFERED=True
+ export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
+ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
++ date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S
+ LOG=experiments/logs/test_kinect_fusion.txt.2018-06-16_19-47-30
+ exec
++ tee -a experiments/logs/test_kinect_fusion.txt.2018-06-16_19-47-30
+ echo Logging output to experiments/logs/test_kinect_fusion.txt.2018-06-16_19-47-30
Logging output to experiments/logs/test_kinect_fusion.txt.2018-06-16_19-47-30
+ ./tools/test_kinect_fusion.py --gpu 0 --imdb rgbd_scene_trainval --cfg experiments/cfgs/rgbd_scene.yml --rig data/RGBDScene/camera.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tools/test_kinect_fusion.py", line 13, in <module>
    from kinect_fusion import kfusion
ImportError: /home/weizhang/DA-RNN/tools/../lib/kinect_fusion/kfusion.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2df12KinectFusion10save_modelESs`

The files exists on path. I am not sure what might be the cause of undefined symbol.

Any comments and suggestions are appreciated.